# Why Map withDefaultValue returns Option = None

Tags: scala, dictionary

I'm using Scala 2.10.4 and I cannot figure out why I cannot get the default value for non existent keys. What I get instead is `Option[Int]` with value of `None`.

```
  val m = Map[String, Int]().withDefaultValue(0) 
//> m  : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map()
  m.get("ss") 
//> res0: Option[Int] = None
```

I expected res0 to be `0`.

Why it is not?
How can I obtain the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `apply` instead of `get`.

```
scala> m("ss")
res0: Int = 0
```

`apply` returns the value type of the `Map`, and will using the default value. `get` returns an `Option` based on the existence of the specified key.

Comment: I feel a miserable Java refugee now. Thanks :)

Comment: @sscarduzio: if it makes you feel any better, I've always thought the `apply` and `get` on `Map` should switch names…